# Converting a numeric constant to a constant string expression

Tags: java, constants

An entity class in my application declares a numeric constant like

```
public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
```

This constant is already used in different parts of the application.

Now I would like to use this constant in a restful service in a parameter annotation. The problem is that the annotation [@DefaultValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) expects a string rather than an int. So I tried using `String.valueOf` to get a string

```
@DefaultValue(String.valueOf(PDCRuleMapping.MAX_VALUE)) final int upperBound,
```

But it doesn't compile, because

> The value for annotation attribute DefaultValue.value must be a constant expression

Can I reuse my numeric constant to get a constant string expression somehow, or do I have to write `"999"`?

Answer (score 6):

The only work around that worked for me so far is defining a String constant as follows:

```
public static final String MAX_VALUE_AS_STRING = "" + MAX_VALUE;
@DefaultValue(MAX_VALUE_AS_STRING) final int upperBound;
```

Alternatively, you can use string concatenation directly inside the annotation:

```
@DefaultValue("" + MAX_VALUE) final int upperBound;
```

Bear in mind that [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), required in this context, do not allow method calls, only operators.

Comment: This should be the answer. Pretty sure nobody wants to see "" + but y'know, It works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only have two options:

- either use a string literal in the annotation `@DefaultValue("999")`
- or declare a string constant:

  ```
  public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
  private static final String MAX_VALUE_STRING = "" + MAX_VALUE;
  @DefaultValue(MAX_VALUE_STRING)
  ```

  If the only place where you use that value in an annotation is in one class, you may want to declare the string constant private in that class.

Comment: String constant won't work. It will give the error: element value must be a constant expression.

Comment: @AhmadShahwan a string constant IS a constant expression, so yes it works.

Comment: Have you tried it? If not, please check here http://tpcg.io/0yhgUG I created a snippet that implements your solution to the letter, and I still get "element value must be a constant expression".

Comment: @AhmadShahwan You were right, because I was using `String.valueOf` - I've amended my code so that it really is a constant.

Answer (score -2):

Define a new constant based on the first one of type `String` and use that one inside your annotation.

```
public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
public static final String MAX_VALUE_AS_STRING = String.valueOf(MAX_VALUE);
```

Then you can have the following, without duplicating the value of the max value:

```
@DefaultValue(PDCRuleMapping.MAX_VALUE_AS_STRING) final int upperBound;
```

Comment: This won't work. It will give the error: element value must be a constant expression.